# What is the best way to wrap this node.js snippet in a function?

Tags: javascript

I have a code example in this format:

```
someFunction(data)
                  .then(response => {
                        return response.text();
                  }).then(text => {
                        console.log(text)
                  }).catch(err => {
                        console.error(err)
                  });
```

I want to stuff this into my own function and call it through out my code.

```
let result = await callSnippet(myData);
```

This is what I've been doing...  **Is this the best way? Should I be using a promise here?**

```
async callSnippet(data) {
    let response = null
    await someFunction(data)
                .then(  d=> { return d.text(); })
                .then(  d=> { response = {success:true,  result:d }; })
                .catch( d=> { response = {success:false, result:d }; })
    return response;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typically if you are waiting to await things, you would await each step and not use then.

```js
async callSnippet(data) {
  try {
    const response = await someFunction(data);
    const text = await response.text();
    return { success: true,  result: text };
  } catch (e) {
    return { success: false, result: e };
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't be using both `await` and `.then()`. What you should do is:

```js
async callSnippet(data) {
    let response = null;
    try{
        var d = await someFunction(data).text();
        response = {success: true, result: d};
    } catch(e){
        response = {success: false, result: e};
    }
    return response;
}
```

The `await` keyword retrieves the value from a `Promise`, so you can't use `.then()` on that value. However, you can achieve the same functionality by using a `try...catch` statement.

Comment: nice explanation and great refactor

Comment: I do not think you meant to use `d` in the catch.

Comment: yeah you're right. misread the code. updated.